# ¿Qué le sucede a mi Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Desde hace un par de días que me apareció la actualización para 19.10, pero me dijo que hubo un error con python "la instalación de python está dañada", por lo tanto no pude actualizar mi máquina. Luego de reiniciarlo para poder arreglarlo, me di cuenta que el mouse no aparecía, las ventanas no tienen los íconos donde deberían estar "cerrar, minimizar, maximizar", no me aparece la barra de abajo (tengo instalado un desktop environment), y ahora no me deja meterme a una terminal ni a través de "Ctrl + Alt + T". Ayuda, no sé que hacer :( ahora muevo mis archivos más importantes a la nube por si a caso. (Me acabo de dar cuenta que tampoco me deja sacar captura de pantalla). También, en vez de aparecer un mouse, aparece una equis. El problema es que no puedo abrir una terminal, voy a ver si puedo adjuntar una imagen desde mi teléfono.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Que pasa cuando intentas `sudo apt-get upgrade` o `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? Si salen errores, intenta ponerlos con más detalle en tu pregunta

Comment: @Aprendiz pues... más o menos. Yo sigo pidiendo en el chat que busquemos tener un SuperUserES pero pues, es lo que hay

Comment: si te parece que si encaja en el sitio @Alfabravo entonces retiro el voto, me guio de ti que llevas mas tiempo aquí que yo

Comment: @Aprendiz nooo, si vieras que yo tiendo a estar de acuerdo. Fue gbianchi el que me hizo caer en cuenta que, pues... no tenemos a dónde mandar este tipo de preguntas. Además, tú eres más sensei que yo :)

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es una pregunta de programación.

Answer (score 2):

creo que lo que esta pasando es que la instalación de Python quedo corrupta, por lo tanto no puedes instalar mas paquetes. Lo que puedes probar es, reiniciar Ubuntu y **limpiar los paquetes ocrruptos** con el siguiente comando en la **Terminal.**

```
sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: No sé como abrir una terminal si no me deja hacerlo, ni a través de comandos :( @Mume

Comment: Pero has probado a reiniciar ubuntu? Puede que sea eso solo.

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de iniciar una sesión gráfica inicia una en consola. Con ctrl + alt + f1. Ingresa tu usuario, contraseña, y luego ejecuta lo propuesto por @Mume.

También en el arranque podrías elegir las opciones avanzadas e ingresar en modo restauración y hacer lo mismo que propuso @Mume una vez que obtengas una consola.

Comment: Hice lo que me pediste , pero no me funcionan los comandos de @Mume , dice "Fallo al obtener ..." y luego pone muchos links :( También que en /usr/bin/python3 hay demasisdos niveles de enlaces simbólicos